# outshine mode changes outline-regexp from markdown's

Tags: org-mode, code-folding, outline-mode, outline

patient StackExchange,

I am learning org-mode and liking its header-folding capacities, which seem much easier than outline-minor-mode. Most of my work is done in markdown mode, though, so I am trying (and failing) to set up **outshine** (from MELPA) in order to get org-like folding and restructuring.

Here is the weird (to me) behavior: with *no change* to my `.emacs` (other than MELPA's adding to `package-selected-packages`), it seems that when I load a markdown file, I can get the tab-folding behavior. This is weird since `C-h m` does not show outshine mode (but it does show outline-minor-mode, which my `.emacs` loads with hooks to text-mode etc). But I don't get any restructuring commands - when I hit alt-down, for example, I get `<M-down> is undefined`.

But if I manually load outshine in the markdown buffer, or load it with hooks in `.emacs`, then none of the folding works - and it seems that's because `outline-regexp` has suddenly changed to an asterisk-based one rather than a #-based one.

So my main questions:

- How do I get outshine to leave markdown's `outline-regexp` alone?
- Should I *replace* outline-minor-mode hooks in my `.emacs` with hooks to outshine, or add outshine hooks in addition to the outline-minor-mode ones?
- Outshine is supposed to also be able to do restructuring with like  and such, right?

Thanks in advance, as always, for your time & attention.

Comment: to start with, it's a `outline-minor-mode` replacement, so if you call for it, change to `outshine-mode`. Sounds like modes clashing.

Comment: Thanks! Weirdly, I get the sorta-folding behavior whether or not outline-minor-mode is called. I remove the outshine and outline hooks from my .emacs, and 'C-h m' will confirm neither outline nor outshine are loaded in the markdown buffer, but tabs will still fold headers locally and buffer-wide - but <M-up> etc don't work. When I try loading outshine by itself, I get the regexp change. -EDIT: I did just notice when I load outshine in a buffer without either outline or outshine, 'C-h m' suddenly shows both outline AND outshine. Is that normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging further, I feel stupid(er than usual). Removing `outshine-mode` completely, I *still* get org-like folding behavior in `markdown-mode`, and this is because [org-like folding is *already* in markdown mode!](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) (See under "Usage".)

As for the restructuring commands (moving one header above another and so on), these are just done by `C-<down>` *etc.* instead of `M-<down>`.

Comment: you know, nothing is as good/bad as it seems beforehand :)